# Bootstrap 4 column layout not displaying horizontally in Shopify theme footer

Tags: bootstrap-4, shopify

I'm customizing the Shopify Boundless theme. I've added Bootstrap 4 via a CDN and I've used it on other areas of the site with success. The footer, however, will not display this 4 column markup horizontally. It only displays vertically.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1022/3186/1371/files/tag- 
logo_white.svg?500" width="100%">
            </div>
            <div="row">
                <ul>
                    {% if settings.social_twitter_link != blank %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ settings.social_twitter_link | escape }}" title="{{
'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform:
'Twitter' }}">
                            <span class="icon icon-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Twitter</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %} {% if settings.social_facebook_link != blank %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ settings.social_facebook_link | escape }}" title="{{
'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 
'Facebook' }}">
                            <span class="icon icon-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Facebook</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %} {% if settings.social_instagram_link != blank %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ settings.social_instagram_link | escape }}" title="{{
'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform:
'Instagram' }}">
                            <span class="icon icon-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Instagram</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %} {% if settings.social_youtube_link != blank %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ settings.social_youtube_link | escape }}" title="{{
'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 
'YouTube' }}">
                            <span class="icon icon-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">YouTube</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %} {% if settings.social_vimeo_link != blank %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ settings.social_vimeo_link | escape }}" title="{{
'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform:
'Vimeo' }}">
                            <span class="icon icon-vimeo" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Vimeo</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %} {% if settings.social_fancy_link != blank %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ settings.social_fancy_link | escape }}" title="{{
'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform:
'Fancy' }}">
                            <span class="icon icon-fancy" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="visually-hidden">Fancy</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- row -->
    </div>
    <!-- col -->
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h3 style="color: white; font-size: 19px;">ABOUT</h3>
        <ul class="footer-list">
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Events</li>
            <li>Press</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- col -->

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h3 style="color: white; font-size: 19px;">SHOP</h3>
        <ul class="footer-list">
            <li>Books</li>
            <li>Posters</li>
            <li>Limited Edition</li>
            <li>Open Edition</li>
            <li>Misc</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- col -->

    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <h3 style="color: white; font-size: 19px;">POLICIES & FAQS</h3>
        <ul class="footer-list">
            <li>FAQs</li>
            <li>Shipping Policies</li>
            <li>Return Policies</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- col -->
</div>
<!-- row -->
<div class="row copyright">
    <div class="col-lg-12 copyright-wrap">
        <span class="site-footer__copyright">&copy; {{ 'now' | date: '%Y'
}}, <a href="/">{{ shop.name }}</a>. {{ powered_by_link }}</span>
    </div>
    <!-- col -->
</div>
<!-- row -->
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

I expected this markup to display 4, equal-width columns horizontally on larger viewports, but instead, the browser will only display the columns stacked.

Comment: I don't find any problems in your code except line 6 there is no class attribute

Comment: Do you want footer inside container or full width?

Comment: The markup I provided is actually wrapped in a <footer> tag that is full-width. I strip the page down to its most basic framework and reapplied the column contents. It displays properly now. I'm not sure what fixed it, but glad I can move forward in developing the site. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this updated snippet

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="row">
     <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1022/3186/1371/files/tag- 
     logo_white.svg?500" width="100%">
    </div>
    
    <ul>
     {% if settings.social_twitter_link != blank %}
     <li>
      <a href="{{ settings.social_twitter_link | escape }}" title="{{
      'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform:
      'Twitter' }}">
      <span class="icon icon-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Twitter</span>
     </a>
     </li>
     {% endif %} {% if settings.social_facebook_link != blank %}
     <li>
      <a href="{{ settings.social_facebook_link | escape }}" title="{{
      'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 
      'Facebook' }}">
      <span class="icon icon-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Facebook</span>
     </a>
     </li>
     {% endif %} {% if settings.social_instagram_link != blank %}
     <li>
      <a href="{{ settings.social_instagram_link | escape }}" title="{{
      'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform:
      'Instagram' }}">
      <span class="icon icon-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Instagram</span>
     </a>
     </li>
     {% endif %} {% if settings.social_youtube_link != blank %}
     <li>
      <a href="{{ settings.social_youtube_link | escape }}" title="{{
      'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform: 
      'YouTube' }}">
      <span class="icon icon-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">YouTube</span>
     </a>
     </li>
     {% endif %} {% if settings.social_vimeo_link != blank %}
     <li>
      <a href="{{ settings.social_vimeo_link | escape }}" title="{{
      'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform:
      'Vimeo' }}">
      <span class="icon icon-vimeo" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Vimeo</span>
     </a>
     </li>
     {% endif %} {% if settings.social_fancy_link != blank %}
     <li>
      <a href="{{ settings.social_fancy_link | escape }}" title="{{
      'layout.footer.social_platform' | t: name: shop.name, platform:
      'Fancy' }}">
      <span class="icon icon-fancy" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Fancy</span>
     </a>
     </li>
     {% endif %}
    </ul>
   </div>
   <!-- col -->
   <div class="col-lg-3">
    <h3 style="color: white; font-size: 19px;">ABOUT</h3>
    <ul class="footer-list">
     <li>About</li>
     <li>Blog</li>
     <li>Events</li>
     <li>Press</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <!-- col -->
   <div class="col-lg-3">
    <h3 style="color: white; font-size: 19px;">SHOP</h3>
    <ul class="footer-list">
     <li>Books</li>
     <li>Posters</li>
     <li>Limited Edition</li>
     <li>Open Edition</li>
     <li>Misc</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <!-- col -->
   <div class="col-lg-3">
    <h3 style="color: white; font-size: 19px;">POLICIES & FAQS</h3>
    <ul class="footer-list">
     <li>FAQs</li>
     <li>Shipping Policies</li>
     <li>Return Policies</li>
     <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <!-- col -->
  </div>
<!-- row -->
 </div>
<!-- contianer-->
<div class="row copyright">
 <div class="col copyright-wrap">
  <span class="site-footer__copyright">&copy; {{ 'now' | date: '%Y'
  }}, <a href="/">{{ shop.name }}</a>. {{ powered_by_link }}</span>
 </div>
 <!-- col -->
</div>
<!-- row -->
```